# Tried to build a Kivy APK using buildozer and got "Invalid syntax" iin runpy.py

Tags: python, android, kivy

I was trying to build a Kivy app as an APK for android. However, when it downloaded all of the needed dependencies it spat a traceback saying runpy.py had an invalid syntax. This is inside an Ubuntu virtual box with Python 2.7.17. It returned a lot of data in its error. The first bit is the traceback that was white, then it had a bunch of red text as well. Both are listed below along with my spec sheet and the kivy code as well. I'm out of my league here and any help will be much appreciated!!!

This Traceback was white:

```
# Android packages installation done.
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=testKivy1 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/thrash/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21'
# Cwd /home/thrash/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 163, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 119, in _get_module_details
    code = loader.get_code(mod_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 281, in get_code
    self.code = compile(source, self.filename, 'exec')
  File "/home/thrash/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1136
    pretty_log_dists(dists, print)
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And then below that in red it showed:

```
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=testKivy1 --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/thrash/Desktop/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     WINDOWPATH = '1'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     LOGNAME = 'thrash'
#     USER = 'thrash'
#     PATH = '/home/thrash/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/thrash/.local/bin/'
#     XDG_VTNR = '1'
#     HOME = '/home/thrash'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '849'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/thrash/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/thrashComputer:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/668,unix/thrashComputer:/tmp/.ICE-unix/668'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/thrash/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID = '107894bcfa81b7e4371588901209427400000006680007'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     USERNAME = 'thrash'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     _ = '/home/thrash/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.109'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/thrash'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/thrash/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     PWD = '/home/thrash/Desktop'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/5e4714c3_e9f3_42c0_ac74_8ee99f74006a'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Spec sheet:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = testKivy1

# (str) Package name
package.name = testKivy1

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = _version_ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 17c

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

And finally the main.py code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        #Creates another grid named self.inside (which will become the sub grid)
        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        #Each one of these blocks is a new widget
        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "First Name: "))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.name)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "Last Name: "))
        self.lastName = TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.lastName)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "Email: "))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.email)

        self.add_widget(self.inside) #Adds sub-grid to main grid

        #This creates the button
        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size = 40)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed) #Binds that button to the function pressed. This is a method inside this class
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

    def pressed(self, instance):
        name = self.name.text #Grabs the text from self.name
        last = self.lastName.text
        email = self.email.text

        print("Name: ",name, "Last Name: ", last, "Email: ",email)

        #This clears the text by making the text box be ""
        self.name.text = ""
        self.lastName.text = ""
        self.email.text = ""

class myApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    myApp().run()
```

Comment: Note that you have `_name_` and `"_main_"` with single undescores. They should be `__name__` and `"__main__"`.

Comment: @buran that was a copying and pasting error. The actual main.py file has two underscores

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this issue,  I hoped onto the Kivy Discord for help and they gave me the instructions to do this:

```
pip uninstall buildozer
pip3 install buildozer
```

Which worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're running python2 but the syntax it's pointing out is python3 only.

Comment: Okay. If I download python3, will it automatically use python3 for the "buildozer android debug" command? or do I need to change some paths?

Comment: I updated my ubuntu to python3, so know when I run python it returns the version 3.6.9. I am still getting this error

Comment: Make sure buildozer is installed for python3, not python2.